# transient fields of case class becomes null in Spark rdd

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I've a case class that accepts an instance of java class LinkedSparseMatrix (package - `no.uib.cipr.matrix.sparse`) as -

```
case class A(mat: LinkedSparseMatrix)
```

When I try to convert the `List[LinkedSparseMatrix]` to Spark RDD, it throws `TaskNotSerializableException`. So I declare the field as transient. But then all the mat fields becomes null which I think is due to default value for objects defined as transient.

So, I tried to define the variable as lazy and thus changing my class to -

```
class A (m: LinkedSparseMatrix) extends Serializable {
    @transient lazy val mat = m
    // some other code
}
```

But now, I'm still getting - `java.io.NotSerializableException: no.uib.cipr.matrix.sparse.LinkedSparseMatrix` - which I don't understand why !

Is there any solution for this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, transient fields don't get serialized... How about making your `LinkedSparseMatrix` class serializable?

Comment: ```LinkedSparseMatrix``` comes from some java library. I didn't define it. Is there any way  I can make it serializable ? I'm not aware of how to do it.

Comment: Maybe you can switch to kryo serialization.

Comment: Kryo serialization threw ```StackOverFlowError```. May be to reading rdd in iteration and merging them into previous one.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reading rdd in iteration and merging them into previous one"? Are you doing something like `listOfRDD.reduce(_ union _)`?

Comment: Yes, exactly - ```listOfRDD.reduce(_ union _)```

Comment: Try `sparkContext.union(listOfRDD)`.

Comment: @Jasper-M Using kryo serialization and increasing the stack size worked. If you like to answer the question, I will accept it. May be it will help others. 
Moreover, using ```sparkContext.union(listOfRDD)``` has benefits over reduce ?

Comment: @Ishan `longList.reduce(_ union _)` will create a very big execution plan of the shape `UnionRDD(UnionRDD(UnionRDD(UnionRDD(...), rdd3), rdd2), rdd1)` which I have personally experienced can cause a stackoverflow. `sparkContext.union(longList)` will create a single `UnionRDD` node in the execution plan. I suspect it will be more efficient either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable Kryo serialization instead of the default Java serialization. Kryo can serialize objects without implementing `java.io.Serializable`.